# How do you access and render html outside of javascript file without node?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, rendering

*** Nobody could answer this question, so another hour of googling and the answer is the Mustache client side template engine.

Hope it helps someone.

I have done a fare bit of googling, about 6 hours worth, I can assure you that this question has never been answered properly.

If I have a JSON load of comments, what is the most elegant, clean, efficient way of returning the html elements to the page using javascript/jQuery?

For example;

```
jsonComments = {"comments": 
    [{"username":"bob", "location":"Earth", "comment":"hello"},
    {"username":"bob", "location":"Earth", "comment":"hello"},
    {"username":"bob", "location":"Earth", "comment":"hello"},
    {"username":"bob", "location":"Earth", "comment":"hello"}]

$.each( response.payload, function( i, val ) {
     var comment = "<div class='comments-wrapper'><div>" + username + "</div><div>" + 
location + "</div><div>" + comment + "</div></div>";
    $('#comments').append(comment);
});
```

that is absolutely hideous, I want that html to be on its own page tucked away somewhere outside of the function. For example, in php I would just use

```
foreach($comments as $comment) {
   ob_start();
   include('commentsBox.php');
   $comment = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   echo $comment;
}
```

and inside the commentsBox.php

```
<?php ?>
<div class="comments-wrapper">
    <div><?=$comment["username"]; ?></div>
    <div><?=$comment["location"]; ?></div>
    <div><?=$comment["comment"]; ?></div>
</div>
```

Need and tidy and beautiful. How do I achieve the same results with javascript BESIDES using anything to do with node.js, I am not skilled enough to go down that road yet. Is this possible?

Or is there a nice way to do while still using php and javascript together, without like I said adding all the html to a json and returning it that way, cause thats just gross as well.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you're going to go down the route of a framework, doing what you're doing currently is just fine for trusted inputs - seems to be just a question of how to concatenate nicely. Feel free to abstract it behind a function, that should be pretty trivial. For reasonably sized projects, I'd recommend something like React to make this sort of thing even easier. `<div className="comments">{jsonComments.map(c => <div><div>{c.username}</div><div>c.location</div></div>)}</div>` or something along those lines

Comment: Isn't there options like jquery load()? it seems weird that you wouldnt be able to d anything like tht

Comment: Sure, if you already have the JSON data transformed into an HTML string on the server, you can make a request to the server and inject that.

Comment: @CertainPerformance right, which is fine to do, but it looks ugly a bunch of html in a json file, because I return counts and other stuff up as well, I dont just echo the html back up.

Comment: @CertainPerformance my return would look something like array( "commentsArray" => $commentsArray, "commentsCount" => $commentsCount, "topComment" => $topCommentsArray )

Comment: @CertainPerformance which is why I was hoping to have a nicer way to display that in the ,.js file and just include those html string when I need them, I can't stand looking at all that + <div> + " etc it looks so ugly

Comment: If you don't want to turn it into an HTML string on the server, then you have to do it on the client. Can't be neither. You'll have to pick one.

Comment: @certainperformance which is my question what is the most elegant beautiful way to turn that into an html string without having all the html cluttered in the return function. I want that outside the function somewhere else and called as needed, cause multiple different Hank strings could be called depending on the return such as “no more posts” = no more posts html element

Comment: Feel free to abstract the code into a separate function somewhere else..?

Comment: Well you actually have answered my question, there is no way, so that is most likely why its never been answered. I do appreciate your time discussing it with me though.